# How does the Spark Driver's memory affect Executor resources?

Tags: apache-spark

I am learning how to configure Spark applications by reading *High Performance Spark*, and one sentence mentioned is confusing me:

> In my experience, a good heuristic for setting the Spark driver memory is
>   simply the lowest possible value that does not lead to memory errors in 
>   the driver, i.e., which gives the maximum possible resources to the executors.

My understanding is that the driver exists in its own node, and executors exist independently on worker nodes. I would have assumed I can max out driver memory without having to worry about it affecting executors.

Is what the book suggesting true? If it is, why/how does the driver memory affect executor resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding `local` mode, driver can be co-located with executors:

- In cluster mode where driver runs on one of the worker nodes.
- In client mode if it has been started on one of the worker nodes.

In both cases driver can compete for the same resource pool as executors. In the first case it happens at the resource manger level, in the second case at host system level.

The second case is less interesting, but in the first on resources allocated to driver, will reduce the pool that cluster manager can offer to the executors.

Comment: @yuuisland Use the --deploy-mode command line argument when submitting applications via spark-submit.  --deploy-mode cluster will cause it to happen.  --deploy-mode client is the default.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the Spark Driver's memory affect Executor resources?

It does not (except one edge case where the driver and executors all run on the same machine).

> My understanding is that the driver exists in its own node, and executors exist independently on worker nodes. I would have assumed I can max out driver memory without having to worry about it affecting executors.

That's my understanding too and can't seem to find a deployment scenario which would prove us wrong.

I think the paragraph without the "i.e." part would make more sense.

> In my experience, a good heuristic for setting the Spark driver memory is simply the lowest possible value that does not lead to memory errors in the driver.

That's perfectly OK.